# Where to find and how to use Ubuntu's version of Windows's Run dialog?

Tags: command-line

I'm switching over from Windows to Ubuntu, and I want to know how to get the functionality of Windows Run dialog in Ubuntu.

In Windows, I just go to the Start button, and enter in the search field `run`, and the Run dialog pops up. I mainly use this program to connect to servers in my network by typing `\\` + the name of the server.

[image: screenshot showing run dialog]

How do I replicate this functionality in Ubuntu? Do I use the command line? I've read elsewhere about an old GNOME program called "Run" that I can get by installing the Compizconfig Settings Manager, but I don't know if this is what I want.

Comment: Regarding recently removed material: For information about what the Run... dialog in Windows does under the hood, I recommend posting somewhere like [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: @ShaharilAhmad Please post that as an answer.

Comment: @ignis answer below.

Answer (score 12):

I believe that the equivalent of windows "Run" dialog is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

In most Linux systems this will popup a dialog waiting for a command.
In the latest versions of Ubuntu, the Dash will open asking you for a command to run.

Of course, you can use a terminal for commands as well. You can open one using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T.</kbd>

I believe that things like the run dialog in Windows and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+F2 in Linux exist as GUI replacements of the terminal, for simple commands that do not have their own desktop launcher in Windows or desktop file in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this website out for a starter,

> 1) [**Terminal**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)
>
> 2) [**Command Line
>   Resources**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommandLineResources)
>
> 3) [**Useful commands in
>   Ubuntu**](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2008/10/useful-commands-in-ubuntu.html)

Thank you @ignis @almel

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of hijacking this thread, and since I am not yet allowed to comment on the above answer, I will expand on this question here.
IMHO, Dash does not replicate the function of the Windows Run dialog.   In particular, if I don't know which application to use with a particular file type, I can enter a file specification in the Windows Run dialog, and windows will (usually) open the file in the appropriate application.   Also, if I enter a directory path in the Windows Run dialog, Windows will display that directory in Explorer.  How can I best accomplish such tasks in Linux (Ubuntu)?

P.S.  Since this is billed as an answer, I can at least add one answer which I have found for the first task mentioned above (thanks to [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/295959/linux-equivalent-for-start-and-open-on-the-command-line)).
 It isn't quite as convenient as the Windows Run dialog, however:

1. Open a terminal window (e.g. by typing Ctrl-Alt-T)
2. At the command prompt, type:

   ```
   xdg-open <filespec>
   ```
3. The file specified in `<filespec>` should open in the appropriate application.

Comment: For me (under Ubuntu 12.04), exo-open returns:
    `The program 'exo-open' is currently not installed.`
whereas `xdg-open` works witout requiring any additional installation.